# Unable to install mongodb in ubuntu 14.04 server

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-14.04

I have tried steps that are provided by mongodb official site for installing mongodb on ubuntu 14.04 server and I have got the following error

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-138-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-138-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-generic-lts-xenial : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-138-generic but it is not going to be installed
 mongodb-org : Depends: mongodb-org-shell but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: mongodb-org-server but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: mongodb-org-mongos but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: mongodb-org-tools but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

So what should I do now.

Comment: related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121180/what-information-do-i-need-to-solve-an-apt-dependency-issue

Comment: to clarify, are you following the steps [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)?

Comment: Yes I am following the steps that are provided [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)